# Read blob zip file directly without writing it to disk

Tags: powershell, blob, odp.net

I'm using ODP.net with Powershell to get blob zipped file.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\DLL\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll")
$OracleConnexion = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection('User Id=test;Password="test";Data Source=10.2.2.1/TEST')

$OracleConnexion.Open()
$Query=$OracleConnexion.CreateCommand()
$Query.CommandText="SELECT BLOB from MyTable Where ID=01"
$ExecuteQuery=$Query.ExecuteReader()

$Path = "C:\temp"

while ($ExecuteQuery.Read()){

   $Localfile = New-Object IO.FileStream("$($Path)\$($ExecuteQuery["LOG_ID"]).zip",[IO.FileMode]::Create)
   $Localfile.Write($ExecuteQuery["XML_TRACE"],0,$ExecuteQuery["XML_TRACE"].Length)
   $Localfile.Close()

   $Zip = [io.compression.zipfile]::OpenRead("$($Path)\$($Executequery["LOG_ID"]).zip")
   $Stream = $Zip.Entries.Open()
   $Reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($stream)
   $XML = $Reader.ReadToEnd()

   $Reader.Close()
   $Stream.Close()
   $Zip.Dispose()

    }
```

As you can see, first I'm writing file to disk with `$Localfile.Write` then with `[io.compression.zipfile]::OpenRead` i'm reading the content of my zipped file.

My code works, but I want to read my blob directly as zip file without writing it to disk, something like this :

```
  while ($ExecuteQuery.Read()){

   $Zip = [io.compression.zipfile]::OpenRead($ExecuteQuery["XML_TRACE"]).zip)
   $Stream = $Zip.Entries.Open()
   $Reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($stream)
   $XML = $Reader.ReadToEnd()
   $XML

   $Reader.Close()
   $Stream.Close()
   $Zip.Dispose()

    }
```

**EDIT : it works with ionic !**

```
   while ($ExecuteRequete.Read()){
$ZipStream = New-Object System.IO.Memorystream
$ZipStream.Write($ExecuteRequete["XML_TRACE"],0,$ExecuteRequete["XML_TRACE"].Length)
$ZipStream.Position = 0
$Zip = [Ionic.Zip.ZipFile]::Read($ZipStream)

$Stream = New-Object IO.MemoryStream
$Zip.Extract($Stream)
$stream.Position = 0

$Reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($stream)
$XML = $Reader.ReadToEnd()

$Reader.Close()
$Stream.Close()
$ZipStream.Dispose()
$Zip.Dispose()
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with `IO.Compression.Zipfile`, see  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile_methods(v=vs.110).aspx for all available methods

You could do it with Ionic zip. It can read zip from a stream:

```
clear
Add-Type -Path "E:\sw\NuGet\Packages\DotNetZip.1.9.7\lib\net20\Ionic.Zip.dll"
$zip = [Ionic.Zip.ZipFile]::Read($stream)

$file = $zip | where-object { $_.FileName -eq "XMLSchema1.xsd"}

$stream = new-object IO.MemoryStream
$file.Extract($stream)
$stream.Position = 0

$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($stream)
$text = $reader.ReadToEnd()
$text

$reader.Close()
$stream.Close()
$zip.Dispose()
```

Here's the doc: http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/Index.html

Comment: You should not read stream yourself, try passing `$ZipStream` to `[Ionic.Zip.ZipFile]::Read($ZipStream)`

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer. Do you see any improvement? I want to optimize it, if possible and reduce number of lines

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with it. You will loose readibility if you will reduce it. I suggest you pack it into function, or even a separate script